# How to parse JSON and display into activity?

Tags: java, android, json

**Goal**

My `Welcomescreen` activity that's the welcome screen when user click the button it fetch the `Google News` and return JSON  to DisplayMessageActivity here i want to display the JSON like beautifully news feed style...

**Achieved**

So far I achieved to get the JSON and using the Intent to move response to NewsFeed activity. Now what to do.?

**Tried:**

I followed [Hooking Custom Layout to ListView](http://[code][text]%3Chttp://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/twitter/5/listview-custom-adapter-example%3E[/text][/code]) and I'm here.. their next session are something different so I didn't followed..

*DisplayMessageActivity.java*

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ListView newsListView;
    //private String[] stringArray;
    private ArrayAdapter newsItemArrayAdapter;
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "HTTP";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);


        //newsItemArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(DisplayMessageActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringArray);
        newsItemArrayAdapter = new NewsAdapter(DisplayMessageActivity.this, new String[10]);
        newsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewId);
        newsListView.setAdapter(newsItemArrayAdapter);


        // Get the message from the intent
        //Intent intent = getIntent();
        //String message = intent.getStringExtra(WelcomescreenActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        //Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + message);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    }
```

*NewsAdapter.java*

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public NewsAdapter(Activity activity, String[] items){
        super(activity, R.layout.news_feed, items);
        inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_feed, parent, false);
    }
}
```

*news_feed.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text="@string/news_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="19sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update:**

after searching I found this [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android) answer ...

tried and it throws ..

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 500 of {"responseData": {"results":[{"G
```

any idea ?

Comment: **Not tried:** googling

Comment: thanks .. can you show me some examples ..? or tutorial ... How to parse

Comment: internet is a great source of the tutorials and examples ... also: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds of tutorials about this, but you should try Gson.
You just have to create a class with attributes you want to parse from the Json. So with a class like this :

```
public class Data {
   private String name;
   private int age;

   public String getName() {
       return this.name;
   }

   public int getAge() {
       return this.age;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public void setAge(int age) {
       this.age = age;
   }
}
```

And a Json like this :

```
{
    "name": "whatever",
    "age": 21
}
```

You can simply do this :

```
public void setData(String jsonAsString) {
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    final Data data = gson.fromJson(jsonAsString, Data.class);
    //And of course access your data like this
    String name = data.getName();
}
```

Of course you don't have to have all the json's variables in your class. In this case with just the variable `name` it would've work.

But of course, the best help would be to learn how to find answers by yourself...